# Component is paste to app.component.html instead of displaying clean component html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I try to create simple routing to show EmptyRoomComponent on button click from app.coponent.html but EmptyRoomComponent is pasted to app.component.html instead of use clean empty-room.component.html

app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {EmptyRoomComponent} from "./components/empty-room/empty-room.component";

const routes: Routes = \[
{ path: 'empty', component:EmptyRoomComponent},
{ path: '\*\*', redirectTo:''}
\];

@NgModule({
imports: \[RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })\],
exports: \[RouterModule\]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {EmptyRoomComponent} from "./components/empty-room/empty-room.component";

@NgModule({
declarations: \[
AppComponent,
LoginComponent,
EmptyRoomComponent
\],
imports: \[
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
ReactiveFormsModule
\],
providers: \[\],
bootstrap: \[AppComponent\]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-login></app-login>
<label class="or">------ LUB ------</label>
<div class="container unlogged">
  <button class="unlogged" routerLink="/empty">Utwórz pokój</button>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I tried to modify routes variable - nothing changed

Comment: Your `<router-outlet>` is in app component. The router replaces `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` with the component. Create another component e.g. `Login` and move your login logic into it. Add `/` route to the router and display `login` in that place

Comment: Im not sure if I did it correctly but it works now. I just need to understand why. Btw I couldn't use **/** route, so I create empty **''** path